# Autohotkey: Find number of matches in a list (object)

Tags: autohotkey

I need to find number of matches in a list. now I can achieve the purpose using a clumsy way as follows:

```
aBlocks := ["A", "B", "C", "B"]
For key, value in aBlocks
{
    a = 0
    if (value == "B")
    {
        a += 1
    }
}
msgbox, %a%
```

I wonder whether there is any readily available function, such as `object.count("B")` [this one doesn't work as it just return the count of all values in the object].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope, no such method (or function or command) exists.
What you're doing is fine in my opinion.

You could create the method yourself:

```
MyArray := [1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1]
MyArray2 := ["hello", "hello", "cool", "array"]
MyObj := {color: "red"
        , mileage: 86959
        , model: "ford"
        , price: "$200"
        , notes: "doesn't start"}
        
MsgBox, % MyArray.CountMatches(1)
MsgBox, % MyArray2.CountMatches("hello")
MsgBox, % MyObj.CountMatches("NoSuchValue")


Array(params*)
{
    return Object(params*)
}

Object(params*)
{
    return (params, params.base := CustomMethods)
}

class CustomMethods
{
    CountMatches(needle)
    {
        for each, value in this
            if(value == needle)
                i++
        return i ? i : 0
    }
}
```

Gets maybe a bit advanced though. A custom function instead of a method would be more simple for sure. Though, methods look nice.
I can explain/comment that code later if you want, don't have time right now. Just wrote that quickly.